# Is there a way to efficiently perform bitwise operations on 64 bit bit-strings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

In a recent project, it involved performing an "or" operation to 2 64 bit bit-strings, but I faced a problem, if the strings were sufficiently large, any bitwise operation would return 0, for example: (this following example may not be a 64 bit bit-string but is sufficiently long to produce the same results).

```js
console.log("10101001010100101010101001010000001010100101010010"|"000100101010100101001010101001010101010100101010010100"); 
// returns 0
```

Is there a custom method I could write for time efficient bitwise operations in Javascript, or a way I could represent these bit-strings differently? If you need any clarifications regarding the question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Bitwise operators operate on 32bit numbers. Even if it supported 64bit, the string would be converted to a number first and `Number("1010")` is not the same as `0b1010`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the introduction of [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) in EcmaScript, you can do the following:

```js
let a = BigInt("0b10101001010100101010101001010000001010100101010010");
let b = BigInt("0b000100101010100101001010101001010101010100101010010100");

console.log((a|b).toString(2));
```

This is what you would do when the input comes in some text format. If however, you just want to have it hard coded in JavaScript, you can also use the literal notation (with suffix `n`):

```js
let a = 0b10101001010100101010101001010000001010100101010010n;
let b = 0b000100101010100101001010101001010101010100101010010100n;

console.log((a|b).toString(2));
```

Note that the call of `.toString(2)` is only there to show the binary representation; the expression `a|b` really is a number of type `bigint`.

Comment: What does the "b" in the bit-string mean?

Comment: The prefix `0b` means that the digits that follow are in *binary* representation. Similarly, `0x` is the prefix for *hexadecimal* literals.

Comment: And when working with even longer sequences, or multiple bitstrings each of which is known not to exceed 64 bit, consider an [`BigUint64Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigUint64Array)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some brute force :)

```js
function largeBitwiseOr(s1, s2) {
  const padded1 = s1.padStart(64, '0');
  const padded2 = s2.padStart(64, '0');
  const left1 = parseInt(padded1.substr(0, 32), 2);
  const left2 = parseInt(padded2.substr(0, 32), 2);
  const right1 = parseInt(padded1.substr(32, 32), 2);
  const right2 = parseInt(padded2.substr(32, 32), 2);
  const leftResult = (left1 | left2).toString(2);
  const rightResult = (right1 | right2).toString(2).padStart(32, '0');
  return leftResult + rightResult;
}

const string1 = "100000000000000000000000000000000000010";
const string2 = "010000000000000000000000000000000000001";
const string1or2 = largeBitwiseOr(string1, string2);
console.log(string1);
console.log(string2);
console.log(string1or2);
```